# JDBC ignores SQLite foreign key constraint ON DELETE action

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I've a Rate table with the following structre:

```
CREATE TABLE Rate (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
book_id INTEGER, 
value INTEGER,
user_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES  User(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(book_id) REFERENCES  book(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

)

And a book table with the following structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Book;
CREATE TABLE Book (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ISBN VARCHAR,
    author_id INTEGER,
    editor_id INTEGER,
    translator_id INTEGER,
    publisher_id INTEGER,
    "type" VARCHAR,
    language VARCHAR,
    "date" VARCHAR, 
    format VARCHAR, 
    summary TEXT,


    FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES Author(ID)    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY(editor_id) REFERENCES Editor(ID)    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY(translator_id) REFERENCES Translator(ID)    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES Publisher(ID)  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE


);
```

So, if I have a Rate entry like this:

```
1 1 4 3(ID, BOOK_ID, VALUE, USER_ID)
```

I shouldn't be able to delete the Book with the ID 1, right?
This is exactly what happens when I try to delete the Book with ID 1 on SQLITE Manager. It gives me
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

However, when I call my delete from the code, it totally ignores the restriction and deletes the book and there's no change in the Rate entry it is still:

> 1 1 4 3

And my delete method is like the following:

```
public void delete() {
        try {
            String query = "DELETE FROM book WHERE id = ? ";
            PreparedStatement statement = db.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1, (Integer) this.id);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When i run PRAGMA foreign_keys on SQLITE Manager it returns 1. So, I assume that the database is created correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) says:

> ... foreign key constraints ... must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the [PRAGMA foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) command. For example:
>
> ```
> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.

Comment: Confirmed. The documentation might be a bit clearer if it said that "foreign key constraints are *ignored* by default": It doesn't prevent us from creating them, but they aren't enforced unless we explicitly tell SQLite to do so.

Comment: How will i call it on JDBC? Possible to provide a code snippet ?

Comment: @SpiderRico Just like any other SQL statement: `Statement s = conn.createStatement(); s.executeUpdate("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; ");`

Comment: @GordThompson 3 hours searching the internet for this information. Amazing how hard it was to find her. Thank you so much for sharing it.